# Creating custom packets on Windows systems

Tags: windows, sockets, raw

I've been researching the creation of custom packets, and from what I've seen it is easy enough on Linux, only requiring sudo and the combination of SOCK_RAW and IPPROTO_RAW in the call to socket().

On Windows, on the other hand, very surprisingly, I have found little information on the creation of custom sockets, and most solutions use one of two librarys: WinPcap or NPcap, which both seem less than ideal for what I need, which is only one or two functions out of these librarys.

Therefore I'm curious if there is any more simpler way of doing accomplishing this task than what would otherwise be time-consuming (compiling NPcap from source, trying to understand the entire program in order to butcher it down, remove constraints, etc).

Surely there must be an easier way to use raw sockets.

Comment: Did you try SOCK_RAW on Windows?

Comment: @Anders I could successfully open one after running my program with admin powers through the combination SOCK_RAW and IPPROTO_IP, but from the Microsoft documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winsock/tcp-ip-raw-sockets-2, you supposedly cannot send TCP data in a raw socket, which implys you might not be able to manipulate TCP headers, which is what I want to do.

Comment: It says XP to 7, who knows about 10. Back in the XP days people used to patch tcpip.sys to remove restrictions...

Comment: Yeah, I'm mainly trying to figure out if it's worth my time learning to make a basic kernel driver for Windows to try to remove restrictions and create an API I could use in Golang. If someone could confirm that it is possible I could make a better judgment...that would be better than attempting the task and then finding out the restrictions are set in stone.

Comment: "*which implys you might not be able to manipulate TCP headers, which is what I want to do*" - why? What is the ultimate goal here? This now sounds like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: I want to simulate a TCP Syn flood from a Windows machine @RemyLebeau

Comment: @RemyLebeau can you answer the question please? I am a starving African in a mud hut btw.

Comment: @RemyLebeau you still haven't answered my question. Also, I have pretty much starved after these months, and I still live in a mud hut.

Comment: @coolguy123 Microsoft's default socket stack won't let you do that. So either find a 3rd party stack that will, or else use a different OS.